# Implementing Subscriptions to Android & iOS App

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-play, app-store

We will publish a dating app to Play & app store in the upcoming weeks. The app will launch as free.

However, after the first X# of users, we want to implement a montly subscription model for new users. In an ideal world, the first set of users will always be free, while the second wave is charged a monthly subscription.

Has anyone implemented something like this before? I could just unlock a messaging feature with the subscription product, but don't want to ding my first users.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem? If your users register with your site/API this should be trivial.

Comment: The problem in my mind is, how do we keep the app free for one set of users, but paid subscription with another set.

Comment: I think it would be best to have registration required before use of the app period, at that time it would determine, based on whatever criteria you have, to charge a user to create the account or allow free creation. Then you just need to maintain account information for each user along with what type they have.

Comment: @BenjaminS got it. We do require reg via FB or email prior to downloading right now. You're saying we can just designate the first, say  1000 userids to be free, while new ones can get charged?